# passing array from java to php

Tags: java, php

I know how to pass variable value to php from java using http get method call.But i don't know how to pass an array from java to php through get call.Any help will be appreciated.

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost/browserHistory.php?mobile_number="+mob+"&arr="+myArray);
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  client.execute(httpGet);
```

i am trying to read in php like this:

```
    $history = $_GET["arr"];
    $result = count($history);
    echo ""+$result;
```

result is always printing 1.

Comment: You have to use a format that can be writable by java and readable by php.

It exist standards like `JSON` or `XML`

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Whoever did DV.plz tell me why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include body into `GET` request (it's not explicitely forbidden by `HTTP` spec) but it's not a good way of doing that - `GET` is not meant to be used to send data to the server.

So consider using `POST` instead or, if an array is small, serialize it and post in query string.

To send `POST` in Android:

```
String data[] = { "String1", "String2" };
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(data));

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// Put correct URL of your web service.
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://example.com");

post.setEntity(new StringEntity(arr.toString()));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
```

Comment: how to use post to send array.can you plz share it. i will also search.

Comment: I've added an example. I didn't compile it, so it may have some typos.

Comment: you are sending String text, not the array.Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. I've added an array to JSON serialization in an answer. On the PHP side you just deserialize it (on example with `json_decode`).

Comment: how can i decode, as there is no key as we do with GET method ?

Comment: `file_get_contents("php://input")` will return the string containing `POST` data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26443/discussion-between-android-killer-and-kamituel)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP allows you to send text. You need to express the array in text. This means you have to encode it somehow.

If you were sending the data from an HTML form, it would be encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The usual way to represent an array of data in that format is to give multiple components of the data the same name. PHP allows for more complex data structures to be represented, but at a cost of losing that simplicity. It adds the rule that the names must end in `[]`, which turn in to `%5B%5D` when you encode them.

```
example.php?foo%5B%5D=1&foo%5B%5D=2
```

This then gives you an array of data in `$_GET['foo'][]`.

Alternatively, you can serialise to another data format, and the encode that. [JSON](http://json.org) is a popular choice.

The same data in JSON would be:

```
[1,2]
```

Generate it using a JSON library, don't build your JSON by mashing strings together.

You could then encode that as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to get:

```
example.com?foo=%5B1%2C2%5D
```

And decode it in PHP:

```
$array = json_decode($_GET['foo']);
```

Comment: See my code added in question.Any help regarding that.

Comment: @AndroidKiller — You have a URL. Build it to match one of the approaches I described in the question instead of what you have now.

Comment: i m sending from my android app.

Comment: That makes no difference to the format of the data you need to construct.

Comment: example.com?foo=%5B1%2C2%5D, how u r getting this ? i mean %5B1%2C2%5D

Comment: @AndroidKiller — Any URL encoding function will do that. I used the JS `encodeURIComponent` function for the sake of generating that example.

Comment: JS means java script ? i will try to find any similar function in android.